# How could I cast a c++ unsigned char variable to a char variable while keeps its value

Tags: c++, casting

Sorry, I have gone through my code and find the place where my problem actually lies.

I hope to cast number in c++ approach. The original variable is `unsigned char` which I stored in a `char` variable `a`. Now I need to cast this `a` to `double` while keeping its original unsigned value. How could I do this ?

Edit:
I didn't expect my problem should be so confusing. Here is a brief example

```
unsigned char a;
double b;
a = 140;
char c = static_cast<char>(a);
b = static_cast<double>(c);
std::cout << b << std::endl;
```

This prints a result of `-116`, but what I actually hopes is a double `140`. How could I do this then ?

Edit v2:

The scene is like this: I read 1024 bytes from a file with fstream. The 1024 bytes contains `int` numbers as well as `unsigned char` numbers. These `unsigned char` numbers I mean to cast to `double` types. I simplly read all of them to a `std::vector<char>` array, and then I need to unpack these numbers. Some part of them are to be cast to `double` and I met my problem here.

If my problem is brought by abuse of c++, what is the correct way to handle this task please ?

Comment: Since in `char unsigned ch = 129; double d = static_cast<double>(ch);` `d` ***IS*** `129.` you are doing something different.

Comment: Casting the value you're describing to a `double` should not result in `-127`. Can you edit your question to include the portion of your code where you believe your issue is coming from?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/
Converting to int from some smaller integer type, or to double from float is known as promotion, and is guaranteed to produce the exact same value in the destination type.

Comment: [§7.3.10/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv#fpint): "The result is exact if possible. If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but the value cannot be represented exactly, it is an implementation-defined choice of either the next lower or higher representable value." So no way positive becoming negative.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Cast it back to `unsigned char` and then to `double`.

Comment: Why do you cast the value to signed char? The signed char can not contain value 140, therefore you get negative number value. Do not use a step between *(when possible)*. When you need to use a step between, use at least short integer (16 bit), or standard  `int` when you do not want to change positive value to negative.

Comment: It does keep its value, but a `char` can only represent numbers from -127 to 128. If you cast _it_ to `unsigned char` then you will see the value remains the same. I'm not really sure what you're doing here though, this may just be an X Y problem.

Comment: You could just stick with `unsigned char` the first time instead of storing in `char`

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
b = static_cast<double>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
```

or:

```
b = static_cast<unsigned char>(c);
```

or:

```
b = c < 0 ? c + 256 : c;
```

Comment: Thanks a great deal

Answer (score 0):

In c++, `char` max number is 127, in the assign: `char a = 128;` you actually get `char` Min value, which is -128, what means that `140` will give you a result of -116. To solve this use `unsigned char`, that have max value of 255. Look at the table of the types Max/Min value that in the link.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fh3a000.aspx

```
unsigned char a = 140;
int b = a;
cout << b << endl; // 140
```

Comment: These things are implementation-defined. Some systems have different ranges for `char` and different behaviour for out-of-range assignment

Comment: @M.M it seems to be relevant to the OP case.

Answer (score 0):

When you store the value of `140` in a `char` variable it will be out of the range of -128 to +127 for the character.

The value of `140` is converted to `-119` The mechanism for this is dependent on the implementation.

The value of `-119` is then converted to double and displayed as `-119` in double.

What you can do is directly cast the unsigned char numbers to double. This will solve your range issues.

```
unsigned char a;
a = 140;
b = static_cast<double>(a);
std::cout << b << std::endl;
```